# Leaflet: Getting Latitude/Longitude in createTile using CRS.Simple

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a simple fictional map that I want to control using Leaflet. It is a flat 2D plane and its "latitude/longitude"/coordinate system spans from `[0,0]` to `[999,999]`.

I have customized the map as follows:

```js
window.map = L.map('leaflet-map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    center: [500, 500],
    zoom: 13,
    maxBounds: [
        [0, 0],
        [999, 999],
    ],
    layers: [new MyLayer()],
});
```

To draw this map, I've created a new layer, MyLayer, which extends gridLayer:

```js
export var MyLayer = GridLayer.extend({
    createTile: function(coords, done) {
        var error;
        var xmlhttprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttprequest.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            done(error, dothething());
        });
        xmlhttprequest.open('GET', /* url */);
        xmlhttprequest.send();
    },
});
```

The problem I have is the URL accepts the `[0,0]` to `[999,999]` coordinate system as parameters but I can't find how to actually get those. I understand there may be some decimal element but I can `floor` that as appropriate.

When centered on `[500, 500, 13]` the `coords` object contains `{ x: 15516, y: -21558, z: 13 }`. When passed to `L.CRS.Simple.pointToLatLng(coords, coords.z)` I get `{ lat: 2.631591796875, lng: 1.89404296875 }`.

I've downloaded the source code in an attempt to understand how this transformation happens from `Map._move(center, zoom, data)` but all that appears to do is call `this.options.crs.latLngToPoint()`, which is exactly what I reverse in `L.CRS.Simple.pointToLatLng`. I'm frankly at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I encourage you to read the [Leaflet tutorial on `L.CRS.Simple`](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) once again. Let me quote a relevant bit from there :

> In a CRS.Simple, one horizontal map unit is mapped to one horizontal pixel, and idem with vertical. [...] we can set minZoom to values lower than zero:

So you have no reason to go down to zoom level 13 on your `L.CRS.Simple` map by default, really. For a [0,0]-[999,999] map, use zoom level zero for an overview, or use `map.fitBounds([[0,0],[999,999]])`.

The values that the `createTile()` method receives are **tile coordinates**, not CRS coordinates. A level-0 tile is split into four level-1 tiles, sixteen level-2 tiles, 64 level-3 tiles, and so on, up to 2^13 tiles at level 13. This is easier to visualize by playing with a `L.GridLayer` that displays the tile coordinates, like:

```
    var grid = L.gridLayer({
        attribution: 'Grid Layer',
//      tileSize: L.point(100, 100),
    });

    grid.createTile = function (coords) {
        var tile = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'tile-coords');
        tile.innerHTML = [coords.x, coords.y, coords.z].join(', ');

        return tile;
    };

    map.addLayer(grid);
```

Second: you want to use the [internal `_tileCoordsToBounds` method, defined at `L.GridLayer`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/f21f2e5b39ad5edba9f1b5c94062a313ee03b946/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L744-L752). Give it a set of tile coordinates, and you'll get back a `L.LatLngBounds` with the area covered by such a tile.

The following example ([try it live here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ShuIKo9tQ7V2vkjk)) should put you on track. Remember to read the [documentation for `L.LatLngBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#latlngbounds) as well.

```
    var grid = L.gridLayer({
        attribution: 'Grid Layer',
//      tileSize: L.point(100, 100),
    });

    grid.createTile = function (coords) {
        var tile = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'tile-coords');
        var tileBounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);
        tile.innerHTML = [coords.x, coords.y, coords.z].join(', ') + 
            "<br>" + tileBounds.toBBoxString();
        return tile;
    };

    map.addLayer(grid);
```

Comment: Thank you, I somehow missed the tutorial link and went straight to the documentation. This is exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: One more question - is it possible to align GridLayer tiles to CRS.Simple coordinates 1:1? In the live demo you posted, you have to go up to zoom level 8, for example.

Comment: You answered yourself: the default size for tiles (256 px) means that at zoom level 8 each 256x256px tile covers an area of 1x1 map units.